# SQL Server full Backup

Tags: sql-server, database-backups

Please, don't get annoyed when I ask this question!

It is indeed annoying that there are so many incomplete answers out there in the internet so if one looks for information he must search a whole day to find the right answer!

Simple question:

**What does a FULL Backup of SQL Server back up?**

Answers found:

- FULL is explained to be different than SIMPLE and DIFFERENTIAL,
- FULL is explained to include only the necessary Transaction Logs.

and so on ...

But NOBODY DOES EXPLAIN

- whether FULL includes the schemas
- whether FULL includes all the indexes
- whether FULL includes all the stored procedures
- whether FULL includes all the views

In other words:

If the SQL Server machine crashed completely will I then be able to reconstruct all my databases from FULL backups ?

Of course, DB Admins will easily find this info because they know where to look it up -
or they would not need this info because they already know.

But for a Developer without Admin knowledge **it is hard to find EVEN the SIMPLEST things!**

many thanks in advance.

Gerald Trost

Comment: Not explained? Rather "you can not read" as the answer by Pedyan nicely quotes.

Comment: See [Full Database Backups (SQL Server)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186289.aspx): *A full database backup backs up **the whole database**. This includes part of the transaction log so that the full database can be recovered after a full database backup is restored. Full database backups represent the database at the time the backup finished.* Is that clear enough?

Comment: if you didn't find any explanation on the internet - then do some experiment on your "privat" db...as i do  -:)

Comment: People should be more understanding. MSDN for instance is filled with vague, often lacking explanations regarding the technical background of various operations and commands. While the documentation on SQL Server is on average pretty damn good and easy to find, it's not perfect. As for OP: A full backup backs up literally *everything* on the DB. But it does not extend to instance level, so while you'll get the users in your DB, you won't get the logins. Similarly any external referenced objects are not included, only the references themselves, etc. But all of what you listed are included.

Comment: "FULL" does not mean "some of it"

Comment: Yes! FULL does not mean "some of it"
Right, this is common sense.
But my Experience with Microsoft Software is many decades long and common sense has been rarely used by Microsoft.
Maybe they see Views and Stored procedures not as "Part of the Datatbase", maybe they see it as Database-AddOns in some kind of sense - I did not know it before.
Many thanks to all the good answers!
and I am not the only developer that was unsure as the votings show - so - again the negative vote on my quesion is inexplicable.

Comment: To marc_s:
No - this is nothing, this isnt even a way to explain things!
When they say "backs up the whole database" then nothing that shows me whether Stored Procedures belong to "the whole database" or not. they could well be "Add-Ons" in Microsofts thinking.
From where should I know it - I cannot smell it!
This is the typical way technicans try to explain things without even knowing how precise and clear explenations SHOULD BE!
Make a CREATE TABLE script, then recreate the Table from script - YOU WILL LOSE ALL INDEXES.
So Microsoft does NOT consider the Indexes as Part of a Table!

Comment: To TomTom: you should not blame a Mathematician that he "could not read" just because he wants to find a precise and complete definition.
To all Technicians:
Please, learn to be exact and precise and complete when you do documentations or explanations - otherwise we will need to search and search again in all the internet and in all the Microsoft sites without finding satisfying answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

But NOBODY DOES EXPLAIN

whether FULL includes the schemas - **YES**

whether FULL includes all the Indexes - **YES**

whether FULL includes all the Stored Procedures - **YES**

whether FULL includes all the Views - **YES**

In other words:

If the SQLServer Machine crashed completely will I then be able to reconstruct all my Databases from FULL Backups ? - **YES** (as long as they are stored remote to the server)

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can perform all the operations you have mentioned from Full backup.

Comment: Why "Oracle?" the OP is on SQL Server.

Answer (score 1):

To provide a little more information than what I had in my comment, the idea is this:

A FULL BACKUP will backup everything that belongs to the DB, basically that means anything under your DB in object explorer, including all schemas, indexes, procedures, views, functions, and all committed transactions up until the backup was finished (even the uncommitted ones which will be rolled back upon restoration), etc.

But often enough a DB is more than just the sum of what it contains:

Its objects can reference linked servers, other DB's on the same instance, contents on the HD, web services, whatever. It can rely on SQL Agent Jobs for maintenance tasks and periodical data fixing and handling, logins, etc. These are stored on the SQL Server instance level. So you can't just up and grab a DB, move it around and restore it to a completely different instance, and then expect it to work on the fly. Those referenced objects, jobs, etc need to exist there as well, including their permissions, potential firewall settings for web services, etc.

This may be obvious, but I thought it wouldn't hurt to point it out just the same. There's really no one list of what all you need to make sure of when restoring a full DB from another environment setup, since it depends on the situation. The person responsible for such recovery procedures should just know what's there and what needs to be taken into account.

Comment: I was unaware of the fact that JOBS do not belong to the database!
Thank you for your precise and complete answer!